# How to align text header inside boarder of div

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put text inside the border of a box on the page. The solution I have kind of works, but the text in the box writes over the header and doesn't scale the way I'd like it to. Is there a better solution?

I've tried a few things like this https://jsbin.com/atupup/edit?html,output but so far have not been successful.

This is the code I landed on:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
    <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
    Section Title <!--Padding is optional-->
    </span>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding:none;">
    <p>more content here</p>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
    <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
 
    Section Title <!--Padding is optional-->
</span>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding:none;">
    <p>more content here</p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI: `<div>` elements are "block-level" and so they already have a width of 100%. `width: 100%;` in your code is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>`, which provides this effect natively and can be styled any way you like:

```css
fieldset {
  background-color:rgba(100,50,175,.2);
  border-top:3px solid black;
}

legend {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:rgba(100,100,255,.5);
  padding:10px;
  border:3px dashed #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>This is the title</legend>
  
  Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here   Other content here 
  
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>    
  </ul>
  
  <p>Just about any HTML can go in here</p>
</fieldset>
```